# What is a distributed database system?

Tags: database, distributed

I comment
I understand perfectly that it is a database but, I do not know what is referred to as "Distributed System".
In this type of systems the information is centralized or in different nodes?
If so, is the same information found on all nodes?
Or, the information is fractioned in the different nodes? (ie each node has a part of the information).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In distributed databases storage is not centralised, different e.g. Hadoop HDFS, a file is split in multiple blocks and each block is replicated within the cluster, not all blocks of a file present on each node, but each block is present on multiple nodes.

For distributed databases both document storage and retrieval (or processing/querying) are distributed.

Check [this](https://www.dezyre.com/article/hadoop-architecture-explained-what-it-is-and-why-it-matters/317) link.